# Can't type text in my input fields in my form (Utilizing a React custom hook for input handling)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms, react-custom-hooks

Ok, I am creating a fairly large form in React (only showing three of the fields here), and thus want to utilize a custom hook for the handling.
I found [an article explaining a way to do this](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-custom-react-hook-to-handle-form-fields.html), however, when I try to type text in my input fields they don't get filled. My console.log of the e.target values it looks like the field gets reset after each keystroke. What do I miss? Cheers

I tried to simplify my code, and hope it makes sense:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

//various other imports not relevant for this issue

const NetworkConfig = () => {
  //Custom Hook inserted here for easy overview. Normally imported from external file
  function useFormFields(initialState) {
    const [fields, setValues] = useState(initialState);

    return [
      fields,
      (e) => {
        setValues({
          ...fields,
          [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        });
      },
    ];
  }

  const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({
    apnValue: "",
    apnUsernameValue: "",
    apnUserPwdValue: "",
  });

  // I omitted the submit button and its functionality in this post,
  // to keep my problem clear
  // The TextField component basicaly just adds some functionality not
  // relevant to this problem. It is tested in other scenarios so in this 
  // case it basically just works as a normal HTML input[type="text"] field

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="network-config-modal" id="network-config">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h2>Network Config</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="network-config-row">
            <div className="network-config-col">
              <h3>Cellular Settings</h3>
              <section className="network-config-section">
                <TextField
                  value={fields.apnValue}
                  onChange={handleFieldChange}
                  label="APN"
                  outerLabel={true}
                  light={true}
                  type="text"
                  name="apn"
                  id="apn"
                />
                <TextField
                  onChange={handleFieldChange}
                  value={fields.apnUsernameValue}
                  label="APN Username"
                  optional={true}
                  outerLabel={true}
                  light={true}
                  name="apn-username"
                  id="apn-username"
                />
                <TextField
                  onChange={handleFieldChange}
                  value={fields.apnUserPwdValue}
                  label="APN Password"
                  optional={true}
                  outerLabel={true}
                  light={true}
                  name="apn-password"
                  id="apn-pwd"
                />
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NetworkConfig;
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `e.target.id` is not corresponding to `fields` object key? You have `apnUsername` and `apn-username`.

Comment: Arh... Of course! Actually tried to change the ID, but realized that the id comes from the name attribute, so when I changed that to match the fields object key, it worked.. Thanks alot!